# Homebrew errors: Unbrewed dylibs were found.., Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install a few things on my computer to run Rails projects. I was installing `Homebrew` and when I did the command `brew doctor` I received the following. I need some help to figure out whats going on.

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: /usr/local/Cellar isn't writable.
You should `chown` /usr/local/Cellar

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib
```

And when trying to install Git I got this message

> Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar

Answer (score 0):

To enable write access to `/usr/local/Cellar` for the current user you should execute

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/Cellar
```

and, for the sake of consistence:

```
sudo chmod -R u+w /usr/local/Cellar
```

from the command line. The former sets the proper ownership; the latter permits the current user to write to the directory. But usually this message means there is something wrong with your environment in general, since you are supposed to have an access to this directory.

Comment: I was able to get pass that issue but now that I am trying to install rails its not working

Comment: Came across this after running `brew doctor`, fixed various permissions issues.... I'm more wondering where that dynamic library is coming from: `/usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib`